# What's the difference between a function that returns JSX and a class component?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

What's the difference between making a function that return JSX, and making a class that extends Component?

```
// Syntax ES6/7

const Banner = (()=>(
  <div>
    My Awesome Component
  </div>
));

class Poster extends Component { // or createClass
  render() {
    <div>
      My Awesome Component
    </div>
  }
}
```

1. Is it true that a function returning JSX is what we known as React Element, and not a component?
2. If the above statement is false, is such function returning JSX is simply a component without state?
3. If none of the above are true, what are those being called?

Comment: Functional components do not have lifecycle methods, [ReactJS Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/07/react-v0.14.html)

Comment: Alright, thanks for the reference link, i guess that clarify all my doubt.

Comment: Also you can drop that extra set of parens if you want. `const c = () => <div />`. In your `class`'s render function you need a `return` statement.

Answer (score 4):

There is an important difference between 'a function returning jsx' and a (stateless) functional component(SFC).

Given this function:

```
const Banner = (()=>(
  <div>
    My Awesome Component
  </div>
));
```

You can't tell if this is a functional component or a function which returns JSX.
This function could be both of them.

When you use it like this:

```
<Banner />
```

The function `Banner` is used as a functional component(SFC).

Besides, use like this:

```
<div>{Banner()}/div>
```

The function Banner is used as a function which returns JSX.

Both SFC and the function returning JSX, return JSX(aka React Component or React Node).
But:

- sfc takes props parameter
- the props are provided with React runtime.

on the other hand,

- function returning JSX don't need to take parameters.
- parameter to function returns JSX are provided use code

Actual gained vdom(React Node) differs depends on which is used.

Answer (score 1):

A Component class is what you would call a React Component. It has properties, state, a render method, and those things you are familiar with.

A [Functional Component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#stateless-functions), on the other hand, is analogous to a stateless component. That is, it does not maintain state, potentially increasing your performance. All such a function does is returning a JSX element; it is effectively a stand-alone render method without an encapsulating class.